# save info of contact form in database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

> I'm working with laravel 5.4.

I try to make sell part (store) in my website and for items that I need to sell I don't want to use regular way!

what that means? usually in commerce websites when you set to order a product you will go to some place named cart and there has all calculations, you pay and it's done.

for me I try to get info with contact form, each item has a form inside and user fulfill the form then the data of user and product will be sent by email to admin so far everything is working but I also want to save these data that been sent by email in other table as `Order_table` and show it to user in their panel that they've been requested to buy those item and if the items been paid or not yet.

Question:
How to save these data in table include sum the price base on selected quantity by user?

this is my form that is in my items page:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('ask_product')}}" method="POST"  id="contact_form">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">UserName</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                  <input  name="username" value="{{ Auth::user()->username }}" class="form-control"  type="text" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                <div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" class="form-control"  type="text" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i></span>
                  <input  name="product" value="{{ $product->title }}" class="form-control"  type="text" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="type">Quantity</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></span>
                  <select class="form-control" id="type" name="quantity">
                    <option value="">Select Quantity</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="More than 5">More than 5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Note to seller</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i></span>
                  <textarea name="note" id="text" placeholder="Your note to seller here..." class="form-control" rows="8" ></textarea>
                </div>
                <h6 class="pull-right" id="count_message"></h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>
```

this is the form validator and email sender:

```
public function ask() {
      return view('frontend.shopsingle');
    }

    public function postask(Request $request) {
      $this->validate($request, array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'product' => 'required',
        'note' => 'required|min:10|max:500',
        'quantity' => 'required',
      ));

      $data = array(
        'username' => $request->username,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'product' => $request->product,
        'note' => $request->note,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
      );

      Mail::send('emails.ask', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('robertnicjoo@outlook.com');
        $message->subject($data['product']);
      });

      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Your Order was sent. Our sell team will contact you shortly.');
      return redirect()->back();

    }
```

here are my routes for that form:

```
    Route::get('/ask', 'ContactController@ask')->name('ask_product');  

Route::post('/ask', 'ContactController@postask');
```

Comment: Why you use route with `get` where your form method is `POST`?

Comment: Check your route action in the form as well as in the route file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after validation you can write the code to store the data into table

```
DB::table('Order_table')->insert(
    ['username' => $request->username,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'product' => $request->product,
    'note' => $request->note,
    'quantity' => $request->quantity]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ORM it would/could look as easy as: (depends on your laravel setup)

```
$order = Orders::create($request->all());
```

Comment: then what about summing the price? and also how would i tell to save it in what table?

Comment: Orders is linked to table 'orders'. That is how ORM works. You can sum the total price on the fly. So, when viewing to the user. Like: echo $order->quantity * $product->price; (for example)

Comment: @RobertNicjoo you can read here how ORM works. Laravel's Eloquent models https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

using:

```
$order = Orders::create($request->all());
```

you can receive all input forms without passing it individually and save it to the orders table.